# How to build different configs in Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, web-config, azure-pipelines

I currenly have an Azure DevOps release pipeline containing Test, Acceptance and Production stage, that are triggered in that order. The Test is triggered when there is a new build available to deploy.

The problem I have with this is that all stages currently deploy the exact same artifact. But this is wrong, since they are deploying to different environments that need to have their own version of the Web.config.

How do I change my setup in such a way that all environments get the right package? Should I change my build setup in such a way that it builds for multiple different configs or should I have separate builds for each environment? And how do I select what artifact each stage of the release pipeline should deploy?

This is what my release pipeline looks like now: [image]

Answer (score 3):

Each environment can have its own variables defined. Simply click on the variables tab and make sure you scope any of those variables to the proper environment.
[image: release variables screenshot]

Then using the Azure App Service Deploy (if targeting Azure) or IIS Web app deploy tasks, you can update your configuration files with the values of your variables, [here is the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops) on how to do so.

Comment: This seems to apply only to WebApp projects. Have you been able to accomplish the same for Console/WinForms/WPF projects?